# Adding JPanel created on netbeans on top of to anotherJpanel created programatically

Tags: java, netbeans, jpanel

I have a panel that I am drawing some stuff on and I want to have an interface on top of it. I created an interface as a JPanel on netbeans, visually. But interface is not displayed properly.

Here is my code

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("WorldGen");

    Interface inter = new Interface();

    JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(lpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);

    lpane.add(panel, new Integer(0), 0);
    lpane.add(inter, new Integer(1), 0);
    panel.setBounds(0,0,600,400);   


    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    main = new Main();
}
```

Panel is declared as a static JPanel.

```
  static JPanel panel = new JPanel()
```

Here is my result: [image]

This is the Interface class that is created in netbeans visually [image]

When I add this line:

```
inter.setBounds(0,0,600,400);
inter.setOpaque(true);
```

this is what I get:[image]

Just a blank screen. I don't expect it to be transparent since I set it to opaque myself but It seems I have another problem. The button is not showing whether I set it to opaque or not.

Why is the button not showing? I am hoping that the button will still be visible when I set opaque to false, after I resolve this problem.

Comment: Someone voted this to be closed for not being about programming? What? How?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by creating a JFrame in netbeans visually, adding a JPanel to it. Then using that panel(by overriding the paint method) to draw my image.